# Can you have a docker copy in the same line as docker run

Tags: docker

I am trying to pass a file while calling docker run.  Is it possible to also execute docker cp inside a docker run?

Comment: What is your use case? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to build an Android Release APK and need to load the keystore.jks file.

Comment: Isn't it possible to copy while building your image?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solves your issue, but you can accomplish this in 3 parts, you can create the container first then copy the file, and finally start the image.

```
host> docker create --name test -it ubuntu:latest bash
7a986aedcd886c6f7e7c65dee8617c05af3e63824e44274e52bc0b4036d81e43
host> docker cp SampleFile test:/SampleFile
host> docker start -i test
docker> cat /SampleFile
```